# Hubot Slack scripting

Tags: laravel, coffeescript, slack-api, slack, hubot

I just got into developing my Slack bot, but I don't know (yet) how to do certain things, or if they're even possible.

What I basically want (for example) is that the bot gets my Slack username and returns it to me.

If I would know how to do this, I could integrate much more interesting things into my bot. I did check the documentation, but (as far as I could see) there was nothing on this subject.

Another thing I want to achieve is making the bot do a call to my custom API.

If anyone would give me a helping hand (example/link to some great examples/documentation for example) I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: This is a pretty good starting point: https://slack.com/developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed yesterday to get the information from Slack using a debug command (console.log Object(msg)). This gave me all the information I wanted.